# Matching TOC-name and title in document for appendix and keeping the defined title format

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, appendices

I am not that good at Latex, but currently I am using a title format creating the titles for my chapters shown below.

[image: Figure 1]

The chapter, 6, and the chapter name, Conclusion, is corresponding to what is said in the Table of Contents;

[image]

However, this is not true for the appendix. The title for the appendix in the document is currently A - Stream Data, like the conclusion-title.

I would like it to be Appendix A - Stream Data with the same title format as for the other chapters. So I want it to say

```
Appendix A
Stream Data
```

Similarly to the first figure. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. And do you think, using a screenshot of the outcome will enable us to give a qualified answer? Please post the minimal code that produces the screenshot.

Comment: The problem is, the less you know the harder it is to post a question that can be answered. Right now, all we could do is guessing. A minimal working example from your side would be needed to specifically answer your question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please take a moment to review our [tour].  With questions like this, it helps if you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess what is inside the files. Following a minimal working example that achieves what you want. You can redefine the layout of chapter titles as often as you want, so you can do the redefinition right after switching to the appendix. But remember, consistency is often better.

> [image: notalatexguruTitlesecContents]
>
> [image: notalatexguruTitlesecAppendix]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{appendix}       
\usepackage{titlesec}       
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\Huge\bfseries\filcenter}
{{\fontsize{50pt}{1em}\vspace{-4.2ex}\selectfont
\textnormal{\thechapter}}}{1ex}{}[]
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Wombat}
\begin{appendices}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\Huge\bfseries\filcenter}
{{\fontsize{50pt}{1em}\vspace{-4.2ex}\selectfont
\textnormal{Appendix~\thechapter}}}{1ex}{}[]
    \chapter{Capybara}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```